# Not sure what kind of sequence this would be.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

Not a mathematician by any stretch, so I am not even sure where to begin to ask this question. I can logic out the answer, but I would like to know the math behind it, so here it goes...

I have a box with 3 sides that can have 4 positions It can be positioned like so:
U ] n [

I call them Up Left Down Right for the orientation of the opening.

Now inside the box, I can have 3 lights Which can be on or off independently. I will try and represent it below:

Bold is **ON**

- 1 2 3
- **1** 2 3
- 1 **2** 3
- 1 2 **3**
- **1** **2** 3
- **1** 2 **3**
- 1 **2** **3**
- **1** **2** **3**

My question is, What formula would represent this? the number of permutations individually is relatively small. But the two combined with any orientation able to have any combination of light on, Not sure how I would derive a formula for it.

Comment: Don't you just multiply $8$ times $4$?

Comment: A formula for what exactly? The total number of states?

Comment: Yes. I want to see what would change if I added a forth light, or a 3rd demension to the open box. IE Forward/Backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $n$ dimensions, you can point in $2n$ different orthogonal directions (counting up and down, for instance, to be different).  With $n$ lights, you can have $2^n$ different light configurations (assuming each light to be labelled).

If you treat them jointly, then, you have $2n(2^n)$ different states.

Comment: Perfect, So If I changed it to say a hexagon rather than a box, I would have 2*3(2^3) = 48 correct? Assuming I had the same number of lights?

Comment: If by $2 \cdot 3$ you mean to refer to the six different orientations of a hexagon with one side open, then yes.